# Illegal assignment from String to List

Tags: apex, webservices, soap, trailhead

I'm getting a Illegal assignment from String to List error in my code and I'm not sure how to solve it, can somebody help please
Below is the code where I get the error:

```
@isTest
global class ParkServiceMock implements WebServiceMock {
   global void doInvoke(
           Object stub,
           Object request,
           Map<String, Object> response,
           String endpoint,
           String soapAction,
           String requestName,
           String responseNS,
           String responseName,
           String responseType) {
        // start - specify the response you want to send
        ParkService.byCountryResponse response_x = 
            new ParkService.byCountryResponse();
               response_x.return_x = 'USA';
        // end
        response.put('response_x', response_x); 
   }
}
```

Below is from where I call the variable:

```
public class ParkService {
    public class byCountryResponse {
        public String[] return_x;
        private String[] return_x_type_info = new String[]{'return','http://parks.services/',null,'0','-1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://parks.services/','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'return_x'};
    }
    public class byCountry {
        public String arg0;
        private String[] arg0_type_info = new String[]{'arg0','http://parks.services/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://parks.services/','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'arg0'};
    }
    public class ParksImplPort {
        public String endpoint_x = 'https://th-apex-soap-service.herokuapp.com/service/parks';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://parks.services/', 'parksServices'};
        public String[] byCountry(String arg0) {
            ParkService.byCountry request_x = new ParkService.byCountry();
            request_x.arg0 = arg0;
            ParkService.byCountryResponse response_x;
            Map<String, ParkService.byCountryResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, ParkService.byCountryResponse>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              '',
              'http://parks.services/',
              'byCountry',
              'http://parks.services/',
              'byCountryResponse',
              'parksServices.byCountryResponse'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.return_x;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are setting string to the `return_x`.

```
        // start - specify the response you want to send
        ParkService.byCountryResponse response_x = 
            new ParkService.byCountryResponse();
               response_x.return_x = 'USA';
        // end
```

But this variable is declared as List of strings.

```
    public class byCountryResponse {
        public String[] return_x;
        private String[] return_x_type_info = new String[]{'return','http://parks.services/',null,'0','-1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://parks.services/','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'return_x'};
    }
```

So you need to set the variable as follows.

```
ParkService.byCountryResponse response_x = 
            new ParkService.byCountryResponse();
               response_x.return_x = new List<String>{'USA'};
```

Comment: Thanks it works well